# VueJs - Setting up multiple proxies in vue.config

Tags: vue.js, webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

So i'm making a API call with a proxy like this:

vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://www.pathofexile.com/'
  }
}
```

xxx.vue:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/public-stash-tabs").then..
```

**This works!** Now when i want to make a API call from a different site as well i'm not sure how to do it. Something like this is what i want:

vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      'http://localhost:8080/one/': {
        target: 'http://www.pathofexile.com/',
        changeOrigin: true
      },
      'http://localhost:8080/two/': {
        target: 'https://api.poe.watch/',
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

xxx.vue:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/one/api/public-stash-tabs").then..
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/two/id").then..
```

But nothing is happening it seems, i'm getting an 404 error because it tries to get something from  http://localhost:8080/api/public-stash-tabs

Am i on the right track with this and am i just missing something? Or is this not the way to go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't seen any examples using the full path like that.  Since it is apparently working for you that way (it doesn't for me), I'm not sure this will help you.  Try to configure the proxy using relative paths as in the [Webpack examples](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy):

```js
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    '/one': {
      target: 'http://www.pathofexile.com/',
      pathRewrite: {'^/one' : ''}
    },
    '/two': {
      target: 'https://api.poe.watch/',
      pathRewrite: {'^/two' : ''}
    }
  }
},
```

The purpose of `pathRewrite` here is to remove the matched portion from the destination URL.  Otherwise it would be appended like: "http://www.pathofexile.com/one..."

I'm testing these rules on a server now, using your URLs successfully (seeing the POE api response).  Don't forget to restart the devServer, e.g. `npm run serve`

Comment: Hi Dan, nothing changes unfortunately.

Comment: Hi.  Ok, I updated my answer.  Instead of just theorizing, I'm using these actual rules right now successfully with your axios URLs to see the APIs.  Don't forget to recompile `npm run serve`

Comment: Thank you Dan! These things also look so simple when you see the answer.

Comment: Haha, right?  You're welcome.  That `pathRewrite` is big and a bit unintuitive.  At first I didn't think of it maybe because somehow you managed to get the absolute path working without it.  Glad it works now.

Comment: Please let me know. How to use the same file for deployment. Means after npm run build and then placing the static file in the htdocs of the production server.