# proxy key syntax in vue.config.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on a Vue 2 app that uses multiple proxies.  This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61291230/2493921) was quite helpful for getting vue.config.js setup to handle multiple proxies.  It uses `/one` and `/two` as the object keys.  The [example](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy) in the Vue docs uses `^/api` and `^/foo` as the object keys.  What is the significance of the `^` in the Vue docs example?

Answer (score 0):

Internally, the Vue.js CLI uses `http-proxy-middleware`. According to their docs, they use a globbing library called `micromatch`. Here is their documentation on the syntax: https://github.com/micromatch/micromatch#matching-features. The `^` represents an assertion that you are replacing the start of the path. That means that if you have a path `/foo/bar/api/stuff`, then the `/api` won't be removed from the path, however, if you have `/api/foo/bar`, it would result in `/foo/bar`. This syntax is however optional to specify and would work without it. It just makes the starting assertion explicit. Here is more information about the start assertion in `micromatch`'s source code and documentation: https://github.com/micromatch/picomatch/blob/5467a5a9638472610de4f30709991b9a56bb5613/lib/constants.js?q=%5E#L92, https://github.com/micromatch/picomatch/tree/5467a5a9638472610de4f30709991b9a56bb5613#matching-special-characters-as-literals.